# Substring search in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have a document that is stored in the elastic search (Search URI being : http://localhost:9200/infypos/product/11111) and data being

```
{

    "id": "11111",
    "name": "PROMO GORE-TEX GLOVE",
    "parent": "ST26923",
    "price": "20"
}
```

Now if i provide the search string as "PROMO" OR "GORE-TEX" OR "GLOVE", i need to fetch the data from the document, like a substring search. I have googled and i didn't get a clear cut answer.
What should i do to do a substring search

Comment: If you have not defined any explicit mapping then substring match will work, could you edit your question with the output of `curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/enerknol/policy_data/_mapping'` and also your query?

Answer (score 0):

To search for substring you better define this field as not analyzed and then use wildcard.

```
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
       "name": {
          "value": "PROMO GORE*"
       }
    }
}
```

To specify not analyzed string you have to specify mapping before you put data in elasticsearch.

```
{
"infypos": {
      "mappings": {
         "product": {
            "properties": {
               "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index":    "not_analyzed"
               },
               "parent": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "price": {
                  "type": "long"
               }
            }
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am creating index by running C# code and passing the JSON data as HTTPWebRequest . If i am to create a mapping or define that field as not analysed, how can i do that?

Comment: You should probably use NEST. (Official Elasticsearch .NET client). You can define mapping from NEST easily. It uses also uses fluent api if you are comfortable with it. See here: http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/quick-start.html